# render elements in cakephp on home.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.4

in my apps I have a view in `CategoriesController` namely "Editorial" and I can show all the articles under that category by `http://mydomain/categories/editorial`

I am trying to show all the articles under "Editorial" category in the home.ctp by `echo $this->element('editorials');`

but it shows `Notice (8): Undefined variable: articles [APP\View\Elements\Editorials.ctp, line 4]`

**CategoriesController.php**

```
public function Editorial() {
    $category =  $this->Category->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id' => 1
        )
    ));

    $this->set(compact('category'));

    $this->Paginator = $this->Components->load('Paginator');

    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'contain' => array(
                'Category'
            ),
            'limit' => 5,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Article.category_id' => $category['Category']['id'],

            ),
            'order' => array(
                'Article.id' => 'ASC'
            ),
            'paramType' => 'querystring',
        )
    );
    $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Category->Article);

    $this->set(compact('articles'));

}
```

**View file:**

```
    <?php if (!empty($articles)): ?>

<?php echo $this->element('editorials'); ?>

<?php echo $this->element('pagination-counter'); ?>

<?php echo $this->element('pagination'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Elements/Editorials.ctp:

```
    <div class="row">
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($articles as $art):
$i++;
if (($i % 4) == 0) { echo "\n<div class=\"row\">\n\n";}
?>
<div class="col col-sm-3">

<?php echo $this->Html->link($art['Article']['title'], array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => $art['Article']['id'])); ?>
<br />
</div>
<?php
if (($i % 4) == 0) { echo "\n</div>\n\n";}
endforeach;
?>

<br />
<br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `$this->render('file');` in your Editorial action and replace file with view file name without.ctp

Comment: Hi... I followed your suggestion but with no luck.. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Something you can change:

```
    1. In controller:
       $this->set(compact('category', 'articles')); // one set()

    2. In view: (Main Point)

      <?php echo $this->element('editorials', array('articles' => $articles)); ?>
```

Here, you need to pass the `articles` variable to element like above, by default an element don't recognize the `viewVars`.

Comment: hello... I just followed your suggestion but still I am getting the same error notice/warning